# How to solve recursive equation $ T\left(n\right)=\sqrt{nT\left(\sqrt n\right)+100n}$

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion

I saw this equation somewhere :

$ T\left(n\right)=\sqrt{nT\left(\sqrt n\right)+100n}$

and I have really no idea how to solve it. clearly, it can not be solved using Master Theorem directly. also I have no idea about any suitable substitution $ m = f(n) $. the recursive tree is also not obvious for me.

I will be really thankful if anybody help me solving this equation.(Or just give me some hints and primary steps).

Comment: For $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: I am guessing the domain is non-negative real numbers, as square root only makes sense in this domain (excluding complex analysis).